# Concatenate two 1 column DataFrames doesn't return both columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I'm using Python 3.6 and I'm a newbie so thanks in advance for your patience.

I have a function that sums the difference between 3 points. It should then take the 'differences' and concatenate them with another DataFrame called labels. k and length are integers. I expected the resulting DataFrame to have two columns but it only has one.

Sample Code:

```
def distance(df1,df2,labels,k,length):
total_dist = 0
for i in range(length):
    dist_dif = df1.iloc[:,i] - df2.iloc[:,i]
    sq_dist = dist_dif ** 2
    root_dist = sq_dist ** 0.5
    total_dist = total_dist + root_dist
return total_dist
distance_df = pd.concat([total_dist, labels], axis=1)
distance_df.sort(ascending=False, axis=1, inplace=True)
top_knn = distance_df[:k]
return top_knn.value_counts().index.values[0]
```

Sample Data:

```
d1 = {'Z_Norm_Age': [1.20, 2.58,2.54], 'Pclass': [3, 3, 2], 'Conv_Sex': [0, 1, 0]}
d2 = {'Z_Norm_Age': [-0.51, 0.24,0.67], 'Pclass': [3, 1, 3], 'Conv_Sex': [0, 1, 1]}
lbl = {'Survived': [0, 1,1]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
labels = pd.DataFrame(data=lbl)
```

I expected the data to look something like this:

```
     total_dist  labels       
0    1.715349     0
1    2.872991     1
2    4.344087     1
```

but instead it looks like this:

```
0    1.715349
1    4.344087
2    2.872991
dtype: float64
```

The output doesn't do the following:
  1. Return the labels column data
  2. Sort the data in descending order

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd truly appreciate it.

Comment: The indentation in your sample code is buggy. Also there are two `return` statements there. Could you please fix it?

Comment: You need to just to describe your problem but make your code demonstrate the problem. Create one single code block, suitable for copying to a file, that when run will import any packages you need, define your function, call it with appropriate parameters, and print the result you're getting. Then show the result you get and the result you want.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. For future requests I'll make sure that my request is easier to read. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two `DataFrame`s, `df1-df2` will perform the subtraction element-wise. Use `abs()` to take the absolute value of that difference, and finally sum each row. That's the explanation to the first command in the following function. The other lines are similar to your code.

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def calc_abs_distance_between_rows_then_add_labels_and_sort(df1, df2, labels):
    diff = np.sum(np.abs(df1-df2), axis=1)  # np.sum(..., axis=1) sums the rows
    diff.name = 'total_abs_distance'        # Not really necessary, but just to refer to it later
    diff = pd.concat([diff, labels], axis=1)
    diff.sort_values(by='total_abs_distance', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
    return diff
```

So for your example data:

```
d1 = {'Z_Norm_Age': [1.20, 2.58,2.54], 'Pclass': [3, 3, 2], 'Conv_Sex': [0, 1, 0]}
d2 = {'Z_Norm_Age': [-0.51, 0.24,0.67], 'Pclass': [3, 1, 3], 'Conv_Sex': [0, 1, 1]}
lbl = {'Survived': ['a', 'b', 'c']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
labels = pd.DataFrame(data=lbl)

calc_abs_distance_between_rows_then_add_labels_and_sort(df1, df2, labels)
```

We get hopefully what you wanted:

```
   total_abs_distance Survived
0                1.71        a
2                3.87        c
1                4.34        b
```

---

A few notes:

- Did you really want the L1-norm? If you wanted the L2-norm (Euclidean distance), then replace the first command in that function above by `np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(df1-df2),axis=1))`.
- What's the purpose of those labels? Consider using the `index` of the `DataFrame`s instead. Maybe it will fit your purposes better? For example:

```python
# lbl_series = pd.Series(['a','b','c'], name='Survived')  # Try this later instead of lbl_list, to further explore the wonders of Pandas indexes :)
lbl_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df1.index = lbl_list
df2.index = lbl_list
# Then the L1-norm is simply this:
np.sum(np.abs(df1 - df2), axis=1).sort_values()

# Whose output is the Series: (with the labels as its index)
a    1.71
c    3.87
b    4.34
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yaniv thanks so much for your help. Your changes totally made the difference.

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help.